# How to write a controller to show all brand?

Tags: magento2, module, controllers

I am new in learning **Magento 2** and I installed a module [Ves Brand](http://www.venustheme.com/theme/ves-brand-2-0/) , now I want to create a page that show all brands I need to create a controller

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using [Alan Storm's code generation tool Pestle](https://github.com/astorm/pestle). It will help you create all the elements of a full module, and helps to reduce the typo hell the new users can get into. For what you are trying to do, you can get deep background with his [tutorial series](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/). But in the short term here is what you need to do to get a controller and a view set up.

After installing the pestle.phar file you can get on the github page, take a look at all the commands with:

> php pestle.phar

To start we want to generate a module with:

> php pestle.phar magento2:generate:module

This will walk you through the needed namespaces ect. you can change these up to your needs. Hitting enter will give you the default value in the ():

```
Vendor Namespace? (Pulsestorm)] Tester
Module Name? (Testbed)] Brands
Version? (0.0.1)] 
Created: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento222.test/app/code/Tester/Brands/etc/module.xml
Created: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento222.test/app/code/Tester/Brands/registration.php
```

The you want to create your controller with:

> php pestle.phar magento2:generate:route

I used these values:

```
Which Module? (Pulsestorm_HelloWorld)] Tester_Brands
Which Area (frontend, adminhtml)? (frontend)] 
Frontname/Route ID? (pulsestorm_helloworld)] tester_brands
Controller name? (Index)] 
Action name? (Index)] 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento222.test/app/code/Tester/Brands/etc/frontend/routes.xml
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento222.test/app/code/Tester/Brands/Controller/Index/Index.php
```

And then we create the view for our route with:

> php pestle.phar magento2:generate:view

```
Which Module? (Pulsestorm_HelloGenerate)] Tester_Brands
Which Area? (frontend)] 
Which Handle? (tester_brands_index_index)] 
Block Name? (Main)] 
Template File? (content.phtml)] 
Layout (ignored for adminhtml) ? (1column)] 
Creating /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento222.test/app/code/Tester/Brands/view/frontend/templates/content.phtml
Creating: Tester\Brands\Block\Main
Creating: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento222.test/app/code/Tester/Brands/view/frontend/layout/tester_brands_index_index.xml
```

You should now be able to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then clear your cache and hit the new view with this url:

> http://{your_magento_install_url}/tester_brands

For the question about getting the brands to show up on this new view, i'll answer that in the other question you have or here:

[How to create a page that show all brands magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220773/how-to-create-a-page-that-show-all-brands-magento-2/)

Comment: No need bash tool to create Magento Module.

Comment: there is no need, but this is an option that people can use to build modules without the kind of typo errors that can stall a build. I make that point in my answer. If you have a better suggestion or solution, please write an answer to the question.

Comment: Use auto tool if only you know magento structrer and can control problem when working in module, if not, you can suggest orther way without tool.

Comment: or you can contribute an answer. The idea here is the best answer rises to the top, not the the best comment.